# Define Range when calling SAGA Kriging from QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, kriging

Is there a possibility to define the range-value or display the Variogram when you call the SAGA-Kriging-Module from QGIS? Maybe by using the python console?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Kriging (e.g. OK) dialogue window, the `Variogram Model` option (default: `a + b * x` as shown in your posted picture) requires your direct input of the equation.

Some models (Exp, Sph) use Range, whose input parameters are defined as:

- a: *Nugget*
- b: Difference between *Sill* and *Nugget* (i.e. *s-n*)
- c: *Range*

(Note that the meaning of `b` in the linear model `a + b * x` is the slope).

For example, to use popular `Spherical Model` (which equation is    `a + b * ifelse(x > c, 1, 1.5 * x / c - 0.5 * x^3 / c^3)`), simply write it into the `Variogram Model` option window with your own parameters like below:

[image]

*(You'll see my Nugget is 0.214, Sill is 1.774, and Range is 514.4 meters)*.

Comment: sorry. I am struggling to find a solution. I thought you might be able to help if I put that into your notice. I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340315/automating-vector-data-entry-in-qgis/

Comment: Thank you ver much, you solved my Problem. Btw is there a possibility to build a variogramm using QGIS or call the saga variogramm from QGIS?

Comment: @Rob I'm glad.  As far as I know you will need to run R through the Processing Toolbox to build variograms in QGIS. Perhaps you can post your question.